Concat Single Quote in SQL Stored Procedure
I am working on a partition automation script and I need the string concat output as below. The prefix and suffix of the query will be framed in separate statements
PARTITION pweek38 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2024-09-22 00:00:00.000000'))

Below is my code
SET @q = 'SELECT CONCAT(@query,'' PARTITION '', @partition_name, '' VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('', @partition_ts, '')'', '')'') INTO @query';

Above statement does not add single quotes between the date time value.

You probably need 4x' after TO_DAYS( and before the closing bracket, not just two.

It did not work. Below is the output on adding 4x'. It doesnt replace partition_ts variable with its value.
PARTITION pweek38 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS(', @partition_ts, '))

It did work in the sense it added the missing single quotes where you asked them to be :)

@Shadow How can this be tuned to meet my requirement

I can't be bothered to remember so use ascii code instead char(39).

@P.Salmon Uff The way you made my day is something beyond your imagination. I had been struggling with this for the whole day and wasted a good 6 to 7 hours scratching my head. IT WORKED!!!!!

SET @q = 'SELECT CONCAT(@query,'' PARTITION '', @partition_name, '' VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('''''', @partition_ts, '''''')'', '')'') INTO @query';
SELECT @q;
SET @query = '', @partition_name = 'PARTITION_1', @partition_ts = CURRENT_DATE;
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
SELECT @query;




@q




SELECT CONCAT(@query,' PARTITION ', @partition_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS(''', @partition_ts, ''')', ')') INTO @query






@query




PARTITION PARTITION_1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2024-09-17'))



fiddle
